VBO - Vega Break Out
Good morning, everyone,
I would need to understand what is meant by vega break out of options on underlyings having themselves an expiration.
The trader showed me a matrix with one dimension consisting of the maturity of the option (example Swaption) and another dimension consisting of the maturity of the underlying (example IRS underlying the Swaption) explaining to me that this decomposition helps to monitor the PIN risk of the options.
Could someone help me better understand this representation, please?
Thank you very much
John

As an aside, I don't quite understand why it's called vega break out as pin risk is associated with (high) gamma. Maybe your trader can explain the choice of word.

"Pinning" the strike means that the option expires close to being at the money, i.e. with the price of the underlying close to the option's strike. "Pin risk" (no need to capitalize, it is not an abbreviation) arises from the uncertainty whether the option holder will exercise an option when the price of the underlying fluctuates close to the option's strike.
Example scenario:

you are long and short a similar option, offsetting each other
you try to guess whether your counterparty will exercise, and accordingly do the same with your offsetting option
however the counterparty does the opposite of what you guessed. (Or, with exchange-traded options, you are randomly assigned an exercised option. However you ask about OTC swaptions, not exchange-traded.) And it's too late to un-do what you did with your offsetting option. You are stuck with unwanted market risk, which may include sensitivities to the price of the underlying or to its implied volatility.

As a somewhat contrived example, suppose that you have written an OTC Bermudan put "P" on underlying $U$ at strike $S$, and bought a similar put "L" (for "long"). They hedge each other. Operationally, the term sheet says that to exercise, the option holder needs to call up the option writer before 11am London time, on annual Bermudan dates up to and including the expiry in several years.
Suppose further that on one of the exercise dates, the underlying $U$ is trading in the market at a price exactly equal to the strike $S$.
If you guess that the $P$ put will get exercised, and exercise your offsetting $L$ put, but you are mistaken and $P$ is not exercised, then $U$ is delivered to you, and you have to pay $S$, but you can sell $U$ for $S$, so you are flat. However you still have $P$, which is now no longer hedged.
Conversely, if you guess that the $S$ put will not get exercised, and do not exercise your offsetting $L$ put, but are mistaken, then again you have to pay $S$, $U$ is delivered to you, but you can sell $U$ for $S$, so you are again flat. However you still have $L$, which is now no longer hedged.
Either way, the remaining un-exercised option has some delta and vega that you don't want and may need to re-hedge at some cost to you.
It sounds like your trader monitors swaptions that are close to ATM and is uncertain whether the counterparties will exercise. There is no good way to hedge this risk.

When the underlying is not very liquid, it gets even worse. In an illiquid market the actions various option traders take to hedge could themselves move the price. The more paranoid traders worry that someone with nefarious intent could try to manipulate the price $S$ to your detriment at the last moment by pushing it slightly above or below the exercise price $K$.
